# Replacing readonly properties on a mocked TypeScript class with Jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I have TypeScript classes that look like this:

```
// value-service.ts
export class ValueService {
  fetchValue(): Promise<string> { ... }
}
```

```
// broker.ts
import {ValueService} from './value-service.js';

export class Broker {
  public readonly svc = new ValueService();
}
```

```
// consumer.ts
import {Broker} from './broker.js';

export class Consumer {
  constructor (private readonly broker: Broker) { }

  public async useValue() {
    const val = await this.svc.fetchValue();
    // Use 'val'
    return `${val}123`;
  }
}
```

I'd like to mock the implementation of `ValueService#fetchValue` while writing tests for `Consumer#useValue`.  I believe this is close to correct but I don't think I'm using the Jest mocking functions quite right:

```
import {jest} from '@jest/globals';
import {ValueService} from './value-service.js';
import {Broker} from './broker.js'
import {Consumer} from './consumer.js';

// "easy" mocking, methods return undefined unless overridden
jest.mock('./value-service.js');
jest.mock('./broker.js');


describe('Consumer', () => {
  let instance: Consumer;

  beforeEach(() => {
    const broker = jest.mocked(new Broker());
    instance = new Consumer(broker);

    // fails at runtime, `broker.svc` is undefined
    broker.svc.fetchValue.mockResolvedValueOnce('abc');

    const mockSvc = jest.mocked(new ValueService());
    mockSvc.fetchValue.mockResolvedValueOnce('abc');

    // ts error, `broker.svc` property is readonly (can ts-ignore or anycast)
    broker.svc = mockSvc; 

    // fails at runtime, 'svc property does not exist'
    jest.replaceProperty(broker, 'svc', mockSvc);
  });

  it('uses the value', async () => {
    expect(await instance.useValue()).toBe('abc123');
  });
});
```

I'd like to avoid having to make my own factory function for `jest.mock(...)`, since the "automatic" mocks more or less do what I need.  I only need a clean way of replacing this top level property on the mocked dependency.

Comment: You don't need Jest's module mocking at all. The dependency's already inverted, so you weren't breaking the Law of Demeter you could do e.g. `new Consumer({ method: jest.fn().mockWhatever })` (due to structural typing).

Comment: The problem is that `Broker` is simplified for this example and actually has a bunch of properties and methods that the `Consumer` might call, and I was trying to avoid having to hand-jam all of them as individual mocks.  I tried to boil down the example; it's already hard to explain exactly what I'm trying to do and didn't want even more boilerplate code getting in the way

Answer (score 0):

As @jonrsharpe mentioned, since the `Consumer` class accepts an instance of the `Broker` class. So it satisfies the Dependency Inversion Principle (DIP).

This means the `Consumer` class depends on the abstractions rather than the concrete class `Broker`. A class can be used as a type/interface in TypeScript. So the `Broker` class in the constructor of `Consumer` is used as a type/interface(abstractions).

We can use the [ts-mockito](https://github.com/NagRock/ts-mockito) package to create mock objects easily, it will help us handle the TS types of mock objects.

E.g.

`consumer.ts`:

```
import { Broker } from './broker';

export class Consumer {
    constructor(private readonly broker: Broker) {}

    public async useValue() {
        const val = await this.broker.svc.fetchValue();
        return `${val}123`;
    }
}
```

`consumer.test.ts`:

```
import { instance, mock, when } from 'ts-mockito';
import { Broker } from './broker';
import { Consumer } from './consumer';
import { ValueService } from './value-service';

describe('Consumer', () => {
    it('uses the value', async () => {
        const mockedValueService = mock(ValueService);
        const valueService = instance(mockedValueService);

        const mockedBroker = mock(Broker);
        const broker = instance(mockedBroker);

        when(mockedValueService.fetchValue()).thenResolve('abc');
        when(mockedBroker.svc).thenReturn(valueService);

        const consumer = new Consumer(broker);
        expect(await consumer.useValue()).toBe('abc123');
    });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/76773739/consumer.test.ts (8.403 s)
  Consumer
    ✓ uses the value (3 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        8.429 s, estimated 9 s
```

package version:

```json
"jest": "^26.6.3",
"ts-jest": "^26.4.4",
"ts-mockito": "^2.6.1",
```